# How to make inline comments in Org-mode?

Tags: emacs, comments, org-mode

In Org-mode there are [several ways to make comments](http://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-lines.html). But I do not know of any way to make inline comments. According to the manual

> regions surrounded by ‘#+BEGIN_COMMENT’ ... ‘#+END_COMMENT’ will not
>   be exported.

But this is only true if the said region starts a line.

In the following

```
#+TITLE: Test

text #+BEGIN_COMMENT comment 1 #+END_COMMENT text

text
#+BEGIN_COMMENT comment 2 #+END_COMMENT text
```

only comment 2 is treated as a comment. It exports (e.g. <kbd>C-e A</kbd>) as

> text #+BEGIN_COMMENT comment 1 #+END_COMMENT text
>
> text

Also, `org-toggle-comment` does not work for making inline comments by using it on regions and `comment-region` does not even create a comment.

So, how can I make inline comments in Org-mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jonathan Leech-Pepin's comment on [your question on `\printbibliography`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134956/avoid-printbibliography-being-swallowed-by-org-mode-headings) gave me an idea.  You can use a macro for inline comments.  Note that you *need* trailing space after the comment definition.

```
#+macro: comment  

...

{{{comment(here is a comment)}}}
```

EDIT: Since this is supposed to be a macro odd input may screw things up.  I'm a little surprised that

```
{{{comment(here is a)}} comment)}}}
```

works for me, although

```
{{{comment(here is a comment) more}}}
```

does not.  I would assume that anything other than fairly simple text would be fairly fragile if they decide to change the way they parse macros in the future.

Comment: That is an interesting hack. You should note that any right parentheses or right curly braces and characters after them in such comments will still end up in the export.

Answer (score 5):

Another way will be to use the export snippets (defined in [Org Syntax (draft)](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html), search for "Export Snippets"), like so:

```
This is the @@comment:This is an inline comment@@ original text.
```

I used the word `comment` where the export backend should be just for clarity, you can use any other word (besides the backend you're exporting to).